# Template Helper Functions

Tags: templates, meteor, helper

Is it possible to pass a variable into a template helper function to determine which object is returned, without creating a new template for each? Something like this, maybe?

```
{{#each frame}}
    <p>{{name}}</p>
    <p>{{description}}</p>
{{/each}}


Template.templateName.helpers({
classic : [
   {
    name : 'first option',
    description : 'this is option 1'
   },
   {
    name : 'second option',
    description : 'this is option 2'
   }],
versions : [
   {
    name : 'first option',
    description : 'this is option 1'
   },
   {
    name : 'second option',
    description : 'this is option 2'
   }],
{
'frame' : function(boardSpecs){
    if (boardSpecs[0] == "classic"){
        return classic;
    }
    else if (boardSpecs[0] == "versions"){
        return versions;
    }
}
})
```

Comment: You can specify context data directly to your template: {{> yourTpl name='first option' description='some description'}}

Answer (score 1):

You can probably play with {{#if}}.

For example only with classic and versions:

Template:

```
{{#each frame}}
    {{#if classic.active}}
        <p>{{classic.name}}</p>
        <p>{{classic.description}}</p>
    {{/if}}
    {{#if versions.active}}
        <p>{{versions.name}}</p>
        <p>{{versions.description}}</p>
    {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

Helpers:

```
Template.templateName.helpers({
    active: {
        classic: function(){ return Session.get("active") == "classic"; }
        versions: function(){ return Session.get("active") == "versions"; }
    },
    classic : [
       {
           name : 'first option',
           description : 'this is option 1'
       },
       {
           name : 'second option',
           description : 'this is option 2'
       }],
     versions : [
       {
           name : 'first option',
           description : 'this is option 1'
       },
       {
           name : 'second option',
           description : 'this is option 2'
       }]
    })
```

Then you can set Session.set("active", "name of the one you want") when you need to change view.